React-table global filtering issue
I am facing a small bug in my react application. I have created a codesandbox and the will link will be below.
I created an editable table component in react with global search, pagination and editable cell. The bug is that if I search for something in the global filter then I try to edit a cell then if I try to click somewhere else the table tries to go back to the first page for a split second. This is only happening when searching then editing (you can also just search then try to click on different input cells and you will see the bug).
Here is the link to the codesandbox that contains all of the code : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/blazing-bird-c7cz3m
App.tsx:
import * as React from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import EditableTable from './EditableTable'

function App() {
const columns = [
 {
   Header: 'Name',
   accessor: 'name',
 },
 {
   Header: 'Age',
   accessor: 'age',
 },
 {
   Header: 'Email',
   accessor: 'email',
 },
]

const bdata = [
 {
   name: 'John Doe',
   age: 25,
   email: 'john@example.com',
   city: 'New York',
   country: 'USA',
 },
 {
   name: 'Jane Smith',
   age: 30,
   email: 'jane@example.com',
   city: 'London',
   country: 'UK',
 },
]

const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => bdata)
const [originalData] = React.useState(data)
const [skipPageReset, setSkipPageReset] = React.useState(true)

const updateMyData = (rowIndex: number, columnId: any, value: any) => {
 setSkipPageReset(true)
 setData((old) =>
   old.map((row, index) => {
     if (index === rowIndex) {
       return {
         ...old[rowIndex],
         [columnId]: value,
       }
     }
     return row
   }),
 )
}
React.useEffect(() => {
 console.log('data updated')
 const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
   setSkipPageReset(false)
 }, 100)

 return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
}, [data, originalData])
return (
 <div>
   <EditableTable
     columns={columns}
     data={data}
     updateMyData={updateMyData}
     skipPageReset={skipPageReset}
   />
 </div>
)
}

export default App

editableTable.tsx:
```import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
   import { useTable, usePagination, useGlobalFilter, Column } from 'react-table'
    import {
      Box,
      Flex,
      Table,
      Tbody,
      Td,
      Th,
      Thead,
      Tr,
      Text,
      IconButton,
      Input,
    } from '@chakra-ui/react'
    import { ArrowBackIcon, ArrowForwardIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons'

interface Row {
  [key: string]: any
}

interface EditableCellProps {
  value: any
  row: {
    index: number
  }
  column: {
    id: string
  }
  updateMyData: (index: number, id: string, value: any) => void
}

const EditableCell: React.FC<EditableCellProps> = ({
  value: initialValue,
  row: { index },
  column: { id },
  updateMyData,
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)

  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
  }

  const onBlur = () => {
    updateMyData(index, id, value)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(initialValue)
  }, [initialValue])

  return <Input value={value} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />
}

const defaultColumn: Column<Row> = {
  Cell: EditableCell,
}

interface EditableTableProps {
  columns: Array<Column<Row>>
  data: Array<Row>
  updateMyData: (index: number, id: string, value: any) => void
  skipPageReset: boolean
}

const EditableTable: React.FC<EditableTableProps> = ({
  columns,
  data,
  updateMyData,
  skipPageReset,
}) => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('')

  const handleSearchChange = (e: any) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value)
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
    setGlobalFilter,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      defaultColumn,
      autoResetPage: !skipPageReset,
      updateMyData,
    },
    useGlobalFilter,
    usePagination,
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    setGlobalFilter(searchValue || undefined)
  }, [searchValue, setGlobalFilter, skipPageReset])

  return (
    <Box>
      <Flex alignItems="center" mb={4}>
        <Input
          placeholder="Search..."
          value={searchValue}
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
        />
      </Flex>
      <Table {...getTableProps()}>
        <Thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <Tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <Th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</Th>
              ))}
            </Tr>
          ))}
        </Thead>
        <Tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <Tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <Td
                      {...cell.getCellProps()}
                      borderBottomWidth="2px"
                      borderBottomColor="gray.200"
                    >
                      {cell.render('Cell')}
                    </Td>
                  )
                })}
              </Tr>
            )
          })}
        </Tbody>
      </Table>
      <Flex justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center" px="25px">
        <Flex alignItems="center">
          <Text fontSize="sm" color="gray.500" fontWeight="normal" mr={2}>
            Page {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </Text>
        </Flex>
        <Flex alignItems="center">
          <Text fontSize="sm" color="gray.500" mr={2}>
            Total Records: {data.length}
          </Text>
        </Flex>
        <Flex>
          <IconButton
            icon={<ArrowBackIcon />}
            onClick={() => previousPage()}
            disabled={!canPreviousPage}
            variant="outline"
            mr="2"
            pointerEvents={canPreviousPage ? 'auto' : 'none'}
            aria-label={''}
          />
          <IconButton
            icon={<ArrowForwardIcon />}
            onClick={() => nextPage()}
            disabled={!canNextPage}
            variant="outline"
            pointerEvents={canNextPage ? 'auto' : 'none'}
            aria-label={''}
          />
        </Flex>
      </Flex>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default EditableTable ```


You can break your component in the smaller pieces so that the updateMyData doesn't affect you or cause re-render onBlur of your text boxes.
// EditableCell.tsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";

interface EditableCellProps {
  value: any;
  row: {
    index: number;
  };
  column: {
    id: string;
  };
  updateMyData: (index: number, id: string, value: any) => void;
}

const EditableCell: React.FC<EditableCellProps> = React.memo(
  ({ value: initialValue, row: { index }, column: { id }, updateMyData }) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

    const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setValue(e.target.value);
    };

    const onBlur = () => {
      updateMyData(index, id, value);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      setValue(initialValue);
    }, [initialValue]);

    return <Input value={value} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />;
  }
);

export default EditableCell;

I have made some changes in the sandbox, You can refer the working sandbox here.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elastic-pine-7fs3zr?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx%3A17%2C1
Hope it helps.

The sandbox link is not working. May be I don't have access to your sandbox can you share access please.

Please give me access

Sorry I missed to make it public, Please check I have made it public now.
